# Angular.js unitest - error when using PhantomJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am Unit-testing my Angular.js project, using Jasmine & Karma.
My config file "files" section is:

```
  files: [
        'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js',
        'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js',
        'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-route.js',
        'http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular-mocks.js',
        '../build/js/*.js',
        './spec/*.js'
    ]
```

Inside my test I use:

```
beforeEach(
        module('MyModuleName')
);
```

When I ran the test using:

```
    browsers: ['Chrome']
```

The test succeeds. When I am using:

```
    browsers: ['PhantomJS']
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module
```

I know this is something to do with "angular-mocks", but I am loading it (and it works ok with Chrome browser). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is module inside your beforeEach block defined?

Comment: It does not. "module" should be part of "angular-mocks.js", which is loaded as part of my test

Comment: Can you log/check the order of scripts loading on PhantomJS?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, works on chrome not on phantomjs